# How to add event click using JQuery DataTables with KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js, datatables

I found demo about knockoutjs with datatablejs. But now I wanna add event click for each row in  table. How do it?

```
 this.selected = function(item){
    console.log(item);
  };
```

[Here demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hwganeqL/10/)

Comment: Could you please provide your html

Answer (score 0):

You can add event delegation on each row level inside handler. Pass "selected" method reference as parameter to handler and call it on delegation.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.dataTable = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var value = valueAccessor(),
      rows = ko.toJS(value);

    allBindings = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor()),
      options = allBindings.dataTableOptions || {},
      $element = $(element);
    $($element).children( "tbody").on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
      allBindings.selectCallback(this)
        if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
    } );
    
    $element.dataTable(options);

    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
      $element.dataTable().fnDestroy();
    });


  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var value = valueAccessor(),
      rows = ko.toJS(value);
    console.log(rows);
    $(element).find("tbody tr").remove();
    var table = $(element).DataTable();
    table.clear().draw();
    $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
      var myArray = [];
      $.each(row, function(key, value) {
        myArray.push(value)
      });
      table.row.add(myArray).draw().node()
    });
  }
}



function employee(id, firstName, lastName, phone, dept) {
  var self = this;
  this.id = ko.observable(id);
  this.firstName = ko.observable(firstName);
  this.lastName = ko.observable(lastName);
  this.phone = ko.observable(phone);
  this.dept = ko.observable(dept);
}

function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.employees = ko.observableArray('')
  this.id = ko.observable('');
  this.firstName = ko.observable('');
  this.lastName = ko.observable('');
  this.phone = ko.observable('');
  this.dept = ko.observable('');
  
 
  this.selected = function(item){
   console.log(item);
  };
   
  this.add = function() {
    self.employees.push(new employee(
      this.id(), this.firstName(), this.lastName(), this.phone(), this.dept()
    ));
    // console.log(ko.toJSON(self.employees))
  }
}

var mymodel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(mymodel);
  mymodel.employees.push(new employee('1', 'Joe', 'Smith', '333-657-4366', 'IT'));
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<table data-bind="dataTable: employees, selectCallback:selected">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>First</th>
      <th>Last</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Dept</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p style="padding-top: 20px;">
  Id:
  <input data-bind="textInput: id" />
</p>
<p>
  First:
  <input data-bind="textInput: firstName" />
</p>
<p>
  Last:
  <input data-bind="textInput: lastName" />
</p>
<p>
  phone:
  <input data-bind="textInput: phone" />
</p>
<p>
  dept:
  <input data-bind="textInput: dept" />
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" value="add employee" data-bind="click: add" />
</p>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I have function selected in model. I wanna use data-bind of KO for tag <tr>.

Comment: Your <tr> are getting generated dynamically so you cant apply KO on those inside datatable context. If you check in handler I am binding your function only passed as parameter to handler. Internally knockout does the same delegation over any click.